School project: folding bridge truss types
I need help researching different truss types and which is the best for a folding bridge. The two movable parts are planned to be  attached to an iron chain connected to a motor that will pull them together to fold.
The bridge (excluding the mechanism) will be made of palm tree timber only. Note that the bridge will at least hold 5 kg of load (vehicles).
Another request is what are the fast resources that I can learn from besides my school curriculum? Notice that I am a 10th grader. By fast I don't mean that it could be read in a week or two, I mean that it shouldn't be intensive. Also can the iron chain be replaced by anything that can be extracted from palm trees

This sounds like a competition between teams for a design class. You should explain what you have considered so far. Also, what bridges have you found around the world that open for boats or shipping?

Open for boats only
